# reactjs accuweather incomplete widget code

Tags: reactjs, weather

I want to add a weather widget in a reactjs app from [accuweather](http://www.accuweather.com/) but i have the following issues :

1. The first one is that i am taking the following alert...

> It seems the widget code is incomplete. Please visit
>   http://www.accuweather.com/en/free-weather-widgets to set up your free
>   weather widget.

i added the script src="http://oap.accuweather.com/launch.js"> on the index.html 
and on the weather jsx i have the following div

```
<div className="weather">
    <a href="https://www.accuweather.com/en/gr/heraklion/2282907/current-weather/2282907" className="aw-widget-legal"></a>
    <div id="awtd1539078558494" className="aw-widget-36hour"  data-locationkey="2282907" data-unit="c" data-language="en-us" data-useip="false" data-uid="awtd1539078558494" data-editlocation="false">
    </div>
```

2.And the second one is that i have to always refresh the app in order to see the widget working.

Any ideas what i could check?

Comment: How do you create your reactjs app?

Comment: With create-react-app

Comment: My guess is that you need to consume their APIs

Comment: Can you explain it moreover?